# Добавить CORS headers в Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Не могу получить данные с сервера. Как добавить CORS заголовки в Create React APP. В каком конфигурационном файле это можно прописать?

Текст ошибки:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'ссылка api' from origin 'локальный сервер' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Пробовал добавить в package.json proxy, подобное:

```
"proxy": "ссылка_api"
```

Работает, но после сборки build, уже через прокси не получается

Comment: Добавьте мидлеваре на  бек сервере.

Comment: Это сервер отвечает. Нужно добавить в заголовок ответа

Comment: А на фронте можно что-то сделать?

Comment: На фронте ничего сделать нельзя.